# Can you commit a mutation from a getter call?

Tags: vuex

My Vuex module looks something like the below snippet. I use a getter to get various values from the parent object based on some logic in the parameters, (e.g. removing some options from a dropdown box based on other values in the object), and for example if something in the state would cause the returned value to have the `locked` property set to true, I want to fire off a mutation call to update the main object. I could do this on the vue level (where I get the computed values) using a dispatch call, but I'd rather not have to maintain that dispatch call in every place my getter is used. Can I call the mutation from the getter call directly? I've tried doing it as shown below but it keeps telling me commit is not a function.

```javascript
var module = {
  state: {
    myObj: {
      propertyA: { /* object with multiple different children */ },
    }
  },
  getters: {
    getField: state => params => {
      switch(params.option) {
        /*logic based on current state values*/
        var ret = state.PropertyA[params.Field];
        if(ret.conditionalProperty) {
          // update state.Property[otherKey]
          commit('updateField', { myValue: true }); // The problem in question
        }
        return ret;
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    updateField(state, payload) { state.PropertyA.Field = payload },
  }
}
```